# How to hide boostrap spinners?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-5

In the parent component, I have `@Input() alkatreszList$!: Observable<any[]>;`which is passed into the child component input
`@Input() item: any;` through `item` object:

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mb-3">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of filteredAlkatreszek; trackBy: trackByItemId">
        <div class="column">
          <app-carousel [item]="item"></app-carousel>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Then, in the child component, I have this container within a carousel.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="img.trim() !== ''">
        <img [defaultImage]="'https://localhost:7094/images/placeholder.png'"
          [lazyLoad]="'https://localhost:7094/images/' + img" style="height: 250px"
          [debug]="true"
          (onStateChange)="lazyLoadSpinner(i, $event)"
          (click)="selectItem(item)"/>
          <div class="progress-container" [ngClass]="{ 'd-none': isItemLoaded(i) }">
            <div class="spinner-overlay"></div>
            <div class="spinner-container">
              <div class="spinner-border text-light" role="status">
                <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </ng-container>
```

These variables are used within the following functions:

```
activeIndexModal = 0;
activeIndexCarousel = 0;  
loadedCounts: number[] = [];

lazyLoadSpinner(index: number, event: StateChange) {
    if (!this.loadedCounts[index]) {
      this.loadedCounts[index] = 0;
    }
  
    switch (event.reason) {
      case 'start-loading':
        if (this.loadedCounts[index] === 0) {
          // Start loading for a new item
          this.loadedCounts[index] = -1; // Set to -1 to account for the current image being loaded
        }
        break;
  
      case 'loading-succeeded':
        this.loadedCounts[index]++; // Increment loaded count for the item
        if (this.loadedCounts[index] >= this.item.kepek.split(';').length) {
          // All images for the item have loaded
          this.loadedCounts[index] = 0; // Reset loaded count for the next item
        }
        break;
    }
  }

isItemLoaded(index: number): boolean {
    console.log("isItemLoaded() called");
    return this.loadedCounts[index] === 0;
  }
```

Problem with the spinners is that no matter I use OnPush / Default change detection strategy within the child component, I must interact with the carousels, or other parts of site in order for the spinners to get hidden after isItemLoaded() returns true. Please recommend better design for this use case, or point out problem(s) with the code.

I am also sharing the CSS ruleset used for the child component, as well as the rest of the template code.

```
  .carousel-item {
    height: 400px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-bottom: var(--bs-gutter) !important;
  }
  
  .carousel-item.reactive img {
    object-fit: cover !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    transition: transform 0.2s;
  }

  .carousel-item.reactive img.hovered {
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .carousel-item.reactive:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  .align-center {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }

  .carousel-control-next {
    width: 5% !important;
    right: 50px !important;
  }

  .carousel-control-prev {
    width: 5% !important;
    left: 50px !important;
  }

  .carousel-control {
    transition: .05s ease;
  }

  .modal {
    --bs-modal-border-radious: 10px !important;
    --bs-modal-padding: 5px !important;
    --bs-modal-border-color: darken(&primary, 10%) !important;
  }

  .modal-xl {
    --bs-modal-width: 1024px;
  }

  .modal-dialog .carousel-item{
    height: 100% !important;
  }

  .modal-dialog .carousel-item img {
    width: 1024px !important;
    height: 768px !important;
  }

  .progress-container {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .spinner-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
  }
  
  .spinner-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -600%);
  }

  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .carousel-caption {
      width: auto !important;
      max-width: 100% !important;
      text-align: center !important;
      display: block !important;
    }
  }
```

```
<div id="imageCarouselCategoryPage" class="carousel slide">
  <div *ngIf="item.kepek.split(';').length > 1" class="carousel-indicators">
    <button
      type="button"
      [attr.data-bs-target]="'#imageCarouselCategoryPage'"
      [attr.data-bs-slide-to]="i"
      [class.active]="i === activeIndexCarousel"
      *ngFor="let img of item.kepek.split(';'); let i = index"
      [attr.aria-label]="'Slide ' + (i + 1)"
      (click)="changeActiveIndex(i, 'carousel')">
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item reactive" [class.active]="i === activeIndexCarousel" *ngFor="let img of item.kepek.split(';'); let i = index">
      <ng-container *ngIf="img.trim() !== ''">
        <img [defaultImage]="'https://localhost:7094/images/placeholder.png'"
          [lazyLoad]="'https://localhost:7094/images/' + img" style="height: 250px"
          [debug]="true"
          (onStateChange)="lazyLoadSpinner(i, $event)"
          (click)="selectItem(item)"/>
          <div class="progress-container" [ngClass]="{ 'd-none': isItemLoaded(i) }">
            <div class="spinner-overlay"></div>
            <div class="spinner-container">
              <div class="spinner-border text-light" role="status">
                <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="img.trim() === '' || !img">
        <img src="https://localhost:7094/images/placeholder.png" style="height: 250px; opacity: 25%;"/>
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" style="color: black;">
          <h5>{{ item.nev }}</h5>
          <p>{{ item.ar }} Ft</p>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" *ngIf="img.trim() !== '' || img">
        <h5>{{ item.nev }}</h5>
        <p>{{ item.ar }} Ft</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This appears to not be a simple Bootstrap spinner. BS5 spinners are as easy as `<div class="spinner-border text-primary"></div>`, and you use `display: none` when you need to hide it. Have you tried just using `display: none`?

Comment: I have tried it with `[ngStyle]="{ 'display': isItemLoaded(i) ? 'none' : 'block' }`, but the style attribute is only changing if I click the carousel, or for instance click mat-menu trigger button from the grandparent component.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by propagating back a state change to the parent component, using `@Output() loadingSucceeded: EventEmitter<StateChange> = new EventEmitter<StateChange>();`in the child, which is emitted when the proper state of lazy loading is catched.

In the parent, I added `<app-carousel [item]="item" (loadingSucceeded)="triggerChangeDetection()"></app-carousel>` and

```
triggerChangeDetection() {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
```

with the help of ChangeDetectorRef class.